# Mysql : left outer join issue

Tags: mysql

I have two tables :
income(month, amount)
expenditure(month, amount)

I need to display for each month of table **income** its amount minus expenditure amount (if it exists).
I think I need to use a left outer join between the two tables, something like

```
SELECT income.amount - expenditure.amount 
FROM income left outer join expenditure on income.month = expenditure.month
```

but I don't know how to do that
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a7d5/1

If someone can help on this sqlfiddle
Thanks.

Comment: If expenditure not there? then ?

Comment: You cannot use month as your basis or foreign key for connecting two different tables.

Comment: What do you mean you don't know, how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that if there is no income then this should be treated as 0, likewise for expenditure.

MySQL doesn't have a full outer join but you can do something similar:

```
SELECT month, SUM(amount) FROM
    (SELECT month, income AS amount
    FROM income
    UNION
    SELECT month, - expenditure AS amount
    FROM expenditure) a
GROUP BY month;
```

This creates a union of the two tables (with expenditure as a negative for simplicity). It then simply sums the amounts and groups by month.

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a7d5/14

Answer (score 0):

Try this OP:

```
SELECT [gross] = ISNULL(income.income - expenditure.expenditure ,0)
FROM income 
left outer join expenditure on income.month = expenditure.month
```

Answer (score 0):

**Query**

```
select t1.`month`,
coalesce((t1.`income`-t2.`expenditure`),t1.`income`) as Savings
from `income` t1
left join `expenditure` t2
on t1.`month`=t2.`month`
order by t1.`month`;
```

[Fiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da2d7/2)